# Why does cancellation block for so long when cancelling a lot of HTTP requests?

Tags: c#, performance, .net-4.5, c#-5.0, cancellationtokensource

### Background

I have some code that performs batch HTML page processing using content from one specific host. It tries to make a large number (~400) of simultaneous HTTP requests using `HttpClient`. I believe that the maximum number of simultaneous connections is restricted by `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`, so I'm not applying my own concurrency restrictions.

After sending all of the requests asynchronously to `HttpClient` using `Task.WhenAll`, the entire batch operation can be cancelled using `CancellationTokenSource` and `CancellationToken`. The progress of the operation is viewable via a user interface, and a button can be clicked to perform the cancellation.

### Problem

The call to `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` blocks for roughly 5 - 30 seconds. This causes the user interface to freeze. Is suspect that this occurs because the method is calling the code that registered for cancellation notification.

### What I've Considered

1. Limiting the number of simultaneous HTTP request tasks. I consider this a work-around because `HttpClient` already seems to queue excess requests itself.
2. Performing the `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` method call in a non-UI thread. This didn't work too well; the task didn't actually run until most of the others had finished. I think an `async` version of the method would work well, but I couldn't find one. Also, I have the impression that it's suitable to use the method in a UI thread.

### Demonstration

#### Code

```
class Program
{
    private const int desiredNumberOfConnections = 418;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ManyHttpRequestsTest().Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task ManyHttpRequestsTest()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var requestsCompleted = 0;

            using (var allRequestsStarted = new CountdownEvent(desiredNumberOfConnections))
            {
                Action reportRequestStarted = () => allRequestsStarted.Signal();
                Action reportRequestCompleted = () => Interlocked.Increment(ref requestsCompleted);
                Func<int, Task> getHttpResponse = index => GetHttpResponse(client, cancellationTokenSource.Token, reportRequestStarted, reportRequestCompleted);
                var httpRequestTasks = Enumerable.Range(0, desiredNumberOfConnections).Select(getHttpResponse);

                Console.WriteLine("HTTP requests batch being initiated");
                var httpRequestsTask = Task.WhenAll(httpRequestTasks);

                Console.WriteLine("Starting {0} requests (simultaneous connection limit of {1})", desiredNumberOfConnections, ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit);
                allRequestsStarted.Wait();

                Cancel(cancellationTokenSource);
                await WaitForRequestsToFinish(httpRequestsTask);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0} HTTP requests were completed", requestsCompleted);
        }
    }

    private static void Cancel(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
    {
        Console.Write("Cancelling...");

        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("took {0} seconds", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    }

    private static async Task WaitForRequestsToFinish(Task httpRequestsTask)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for HTTP requests to finish");

        try
        {
            await httpRequestsTask;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HTTP requests were cancelled");
        }
    }

    private static async Task GetHttpResponse(HttpClient client, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action reportStarted, Action reportFinished)
    {
        var getResponse = client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com", cancellationToken);

        reportStarted();
        using (var response = await getResponse)
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        reportFinished();
    }
}
```

#### Output

[image: Console window showing that cancellation blocked for over 13 seconds]

**Why does cancellation block for so long?** Also, is there anything that I'm doing wrong or could be doing better?

Comment: It's amazing that we've hit the same "bottleneck" and asked almost identical questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71278835/why-task-cancellation-takes-so-long-in-flurl-http-downloadfileasync-httpclient

Answer (score 5):

> Performing the CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() method call in a non-UI thread. This didn't work too well; the task didn't actually run until most of the others had finished.

What this tells me is that you're probably suffering from 'threadpool exhaustion', which is where your threadpool queue has so many items in it (from HTTP requests completing) that it takes a while to get through them all. Cancellation probably is blocking on some threadpool work item executing and it can't skip to the head of the queue.

This suggests that you do need to go with option 1 from your consideration list. Throttle your own work so that the threadpool queue remains relatively short. This is good for app responsiveness overall anyway.

My favorite way to throttle async work is to use [Dataflow](http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft.tpl.dataflow). Something like this:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<Uri>(
    async uri => {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(); // HttpClient isn't thread-safe, so protect against concurrency by using a dedicated instance for each request.
        var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
        // do more stuff with result.
    },
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20, CancellationToken = cancellationToken });
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    block.Post(new Uri("http://www.server.com/req" + i));
block.Complete();
await block.Completion; // waits until everything is done or canceled.
```

As an alternative, you could use Task.Factory.StartNew passing in TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning so your task gets a *new* thread (not affiliated with threadpool) which would allow it to start immediately and call Cancel from there. But you should probably solve the threadpool exhaustion problem instead.

Comment: Is there some way to avoid the creation of additional threads for the HTTP requests? I recall reading that using `await` with `GetAsync` will not cause a new thread to be created.

Comment: It's not that it creates new threads. It's just that when the HTTP response comes in, a threadpool thread is occupied to handle that response. The threadpool only has so many threads (usually 4 on a quad core) under typical workloads. So if you have hundreds of web requests, you'll have four or more active threads receiving the responses once they come in, and the rest of the responses are waiting in the threadpool queue, causing the backlog you're seeing.

Comment: @Sam so what solution did you use ? I currently encounter the same problem

Comment: @Gui, I think I experimented with the suggestion in this answer, but in the end I don't recall implementing something I was happy with. The project I was working on was just a personal project, and due to external factors, I stopped working on it.